# Chrome doesn't display full page overlay in certain situations

Tags: google-chrome

I am using jQuery blockUI 2.47 (28-SEP-2012) in many of my project, to display full-page overlay with some animation, on every page unload. This code hasn't been changed for past few months, but for past few weeks I started to notice, that in certain situations, on Chrome 33.0.1750.146 (others seems to be unaffected), I don't see that opacity overlay at all.

**It happens only on Chrome** (haven't noticed it in other browsers yet) and **in certain situations only** -- for example only on login screen (others are fine).

I know, that this is hard to belive, so here you have some screenshots, that proves this.

a) a typical page, where Chrome displays full-page overlay without any problems and as previously:

[image]

b) a login screen, *from the very same webpage*, where Chrome stopped displaying overlay (but it was displaying it for past nearly a year, so it started to happen with some newest update):

[image]

c) the same login screen, *from the same webpage*, as seen under Firefox (overlay displayed):

[image]

I'm 99.99% sure (I reserve 0.01% for the unicorns), that this is **not** developer / code problem!

Because:

- it happens only on Chrome and only on certain parts of the page,
- all situations (all screenshots captured) are handled by the same code (`onUnload`),
- the code hasn't changed for past nine months or so, though strange things (lacks of full-page overlay) started to happen about a month ago or so.

So, I assume, that this is Chrome-specific problem and may have to be somehow related to Chrome's rendering engine.

It -- of course -- happens on any copy of Chrome, that I use -- home, office etc. So, I don't think, that full, clean reinstall Chrome would do anything (though I haven't tried this).

Can anyone verify this or heard about similar strange thing?

Side note: This is another strange change (after [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57001/21486)), that happens to me, when using Chrome or other Google products (Gmail). No one else can confirm this, but I have a screenshots, that proves, that I'm not lunatic. I really begin to think, that developers at Google started to screw thing after thing, and that this might be a good moment to say bye, bye!